# cannot load different page on angular spa

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, single-page-application

I am building an angular app on an express/node server. There are two pages. I set them on `app.js`

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/', routes.list);
app.use('/users/', users.showUsers);
```

here are the routes (`index.js` and `users.js`)

```
exports.list = function(req, res){
res.render('index')
};

exports.showUsers = function(req, res){
res.render('users')
};
```

Now, `users.ejs` is just a dummy page like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >    
    <div id="main">
     this is where content will be injected 
    </div>
</html>
```

but the `index.ejs` is spa style like

```
<html ng-app="sp">
var sp = angular.module('sp', ['ngRoute']);

sp.config(function ($routeProvider,  $locationProvider) {
    // configure the routes


    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
    // route for the home page
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost:4800/home.html',
        controller: 'homeController'
    })

    .when('/about', {
    // route for the about page
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost:4800/about.html',
        controller: 'aboutController'
    })
    .otherwise({
        templateUrl: 'http://localhost:4800/routeNotFound.html',
       controller: 'notFoundController'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

});

sp.controller('homeController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Welcome to my home page!';
});

sp.controller('aboutController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Find out more about us.';
});

   sp.controller('notFoundController', function ($scope) {
       $scope.message = 'There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted';
    });

<li><a href="/"> Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about"> About</a></li>          
<li><a href="/users/"> users</a></li>

    <div id="main">
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

The links are the menu and the different tamplates of the index load in the `main div`. But when I click on the `<li><a href="/users/"> users</a></li>` it doesn load the page, it thinks is another template to load in index and fails. I even try to set the link differently like `http://localhost:4800/users`, nothing. Should I set another `when` in the `routeProvider` and then reload the page for `users`? Is there a smarter way to do this by not using the `routeProvider`? I declared a different route in `app.js` for `users`, why it doesnt just load the page ?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE

I changed this

```
app.use('/', routes.list);
app.use('/users/', users.showUsers);
```

to this

```
app.get('/', routes.list);
app.get('/users/', users.showUsers);
```

and still nothing

UPDATE 2
I also have an `otherwise` case in the routing and a relative "notFoundController" controller. I didnt include them at first, to make the question short. When I click users, I get "There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted" on the page.

UPDATE 3
My original code is
`sp.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {` . In the same config function there is 
`$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');`. If remove it and change the menu url prefixes from `/` to `#` (users has still `/`)it all works fine. But I dont get why html 5 mode breaks the whole code and I dont want to use `#`

Comment: You have already declared the routes on `app.js`. Why are you declaring them again with Angular?

Comment: @AbraarArique There is a difference. I am declaring routes to pages in `app.js` and routes to spa templates in angular.

Comment: What error (in the developer console) do you get when you go to the angular page?

Comment: @thinkwinwin No errors in the cosole. I have an `otherwise` case in routing and a relative controller. I didnt include them at first, to make the question short. I put them now. Check OP. So I dont see errors in the console, just `There seems to be a problem finding the page you wanted` on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 <li><a href="/users/" target="_self"> users</a></li>
```

the `target` attribute will force angular to not use their own routing, only do a server request.